# Search a list of nested tuples of strings in python

Tags: python, nested, tuples, flatten

Lets say I have a list x:

```
x=['alfa[1]', 'bravo', ('charlie[7]', 'delta[2]'), 'echo[3]']
```

I want to create a new list which both flattens and removes the bracketed number if the item has one.  The result should be:

```
x_flattened_bases = ['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
x_flattened_bases = []
for item in x:
    if isinstance(item, tuple):
        x_flattened_bases.extend([value.split('[')[0] for value in item)
    else:
        x_flattened_bases.append(item.split('[')[0])
```

There is only 1 level of nesting in the list.

Comment: sometimes the more verbose code is the more readable code

Comment: 6 lines for this doesn't seem too bad to me XD

Comment: show us what you got, im sure someone will help clean it up

Comment: Is the nesting arbitrarily deep?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
import collections
import re
def solve(lis):
  for element in lis:
    if isinstance(element, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(element,str):
      for x in solve(element):
        yield re.sub(r"\[\d+\]",r"",x)
    else:
      yield re.sub(r"\[\d+\]",r"",element)

x=['alfa[1]', 'bravo', ('charlie[7]', 'delta[2]'), 'echo[3]']
print list(solve(x))
```

**output:**

```
['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
```

Comment: @Darko Don'try to post code in comments, update the question instead

Answer (score 3):

Flatten [questions have been answered many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python).

**tl;dr** use the horribly document [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast) module's flatten function

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten([1,2,['dflkjasdf','ok'],'ok'])
[1, 2, 'dflkjasdf', 'ok', 'ok']
```

A one-liner that also strips out [] (assuming all child nodes are strings):

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>>def flattenstrip(input): return [el[:el.find('[')] if el.find('[')!=-1 else el for el in  flatten(input)]
>>>flattenstrip(['alfa[1]', 'bravo', ('charlie[7]', 'delta[2]'), 'echo[3]'])
>>>['alfa', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, but it makes a lot of assumptions about the structure (i.e. just one level of nesting, `string`s only)...

```
from itertools import chain

lst = ['alfa[1]', 'bravo', ('charlie[7]', 'delta[2]'), 'echo[3]']

flattened = chain.from_iterable([x] if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst)
result = [x.rsplit('[', 1)[0] for x in flattened]
```

It gets tidier when you give the focussed operations a name:

```
def flatten(it):
    return chain.from_iterable([x] if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst)

def clean(it):
    return (x.rsplit('[', 1)[0] for x in it)

result = list(clean(flatten(lst)))
```

If you want to stay closer to the code you have, you could clean it up by using recursion.

```
def process(lst, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            result.append(item.rsplit('[', 1)[0])
        else:
            process(item, result)
    return result

result = process(lst)
```

**Edit**

More succinct thanks to inspiration from @yoonkwon, but please note that `compiler.ast` is deprecated and no longer exists in Python 3:

```
from compiler.ast import flatten

result = [item.rsplit('[', 1)[0] for item in flatten(lst)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flattening and cleaning words are two separate tasks. [Funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library has functions [flatten](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#flatten) and [re_find](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/strings.html#re_find) to solve them:

```
from funcy import flatten, re_find
flat_list = [re_find(r'^\w+') for word in flatten(your_list)]
```

Or this can be done more efficiently with slightly other functions:

```
from funcy import iflatten, re_finder
flat_list = map(re_finder(r'^\w+'), iflatten(your_list))
```